# How to display 1st date of month as column name in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to display 1st date of current month as column name in SQL

I wrote the below query, but not getting correct column name

```
SELECT  Citrix_ID as [Citrix ID], Full_Name as [Full Name]
  , Band, Cigna_DOJ as [Cigna DOJ]
  , [01] +' as ' + '''' + SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0),106) + '''' 
FROM [dbo].[admin.Attendance]
```

Comment: dbms name please

Comment: It is SQL Server

Comment: Any particular query always gives a result set with the same "shape" - the number of columns, their *names* and types. You either a) have to go a dynamic SQL route to construct a new query on the fly or b) Use a fixed column name and do something in your *presentation* layer to apply a variable label to that column. I'd strongly suggest (b).

Comment: @SudhakarChitlam . . . You would need to use dynamic SQL.  In a `SELECT` statement, the columns have fixed names.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Dynamic Sql for such things.

**Example snippet:**

```
declare @FirstDayOfMonth date = dateadd(day,1,eomonth(GetDate(),-1));
declare @ColName varchar(30) = quotename(format(@FirstDayOfMonth,'dd-MMM-yyyy'));

declare @DynSql nvarchar(max);

-- build the string for the actual query 
set  @DynSql = 'select 1 as '+ @ColName;

-- test how it looks
select @DynSql as DynSql;

-- run it
exec(@DynSql);
```

**Result:**

```
01-Jan-2019
-----------
1
```

For your query the string could be constructed like this:

```
set  @DynSql = 'SELECT'+char(10)+
 '  Citrix_ID as [Citrix ID]'+char(10)+
 ', Full_Name as [Full Name]'+char(10)+
 ', Band'+char(10)+
 ', Cigna_DOJ as [Cigna DOJ]'+char(10)+
 ', [01]  as '+ @ColName +char(10)+
 'FROM [dbo].[admin.Attendance]';
```

*Note that in Ms Sql Server 2017+ there's a [CONCAT_WS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-ws-transact-sql)*

Comment: Also, look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql).  Using parameters can prevent hacking through Sql Injection.

Comment: I used EXEC for the example because the `@ColName` variable doesn't come from user input.  But concatinating data from user input to the string is a risk. It could contain sql.

Answer (score 0):

Try like below

```
SELECT SELECT format( DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0,getdate()), 0),'dd-MMM-yyyy') AS _stday AS firstday,Citrix_ID as [Citrix ID], Full_Name as [Full Name], Band, Cigna_DOJ as [Cigna DOJ]
FROM [dbo].[admin.Attendance]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I need the column name should be like '01-Jan-2019'

Comment: Thanks, I need the output not column name as firstday. I need the column name should be 01-Jan-2019

Comment: [column name] as [DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0,getdate()), 0),'dd-MMM-yyyy')]

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0),101)       as FirstDateOfMonth
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use `REPLACE` function

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()),0),106),' ', '-') 
       as FirstDateOfTheMonth;

01-Jan-2019
```